# Is there a way to get alert when the rest api is called in golang

Tags: postgresql, rest, go, design-patterns, architecture

I have a golang system_info rest service that does basic CRUD operations. Its service that captures the some basic system information and updates to the server. THis System_info Rest api is hosted as microservice using Kubernetes.

But, the service before capturing any details from system requires the IP address and whoever prepares the system calls my rest endpoint uploads basic information like IP address and hostname.

Now, once this IP address is uploaded to postgres table using system_info rest api endpoints, the system_info rest service should ping these IP addresses and check if they are getting any response and would update the status that machine is up and running.

How do I achieve this, the service is running in Kube - once endpoint is called and IP address are updated, how would service know that table has IP address and now service should PING these IP addresses ?

What I am thinking is one of the two approaches

1. When rest endpoint to update IP address is called, then only capture the IP address and ping each one of them and capture the status and update the status column in postgres, but this significantly slows down the create/update operation as service needs ping each IP and wait for response and upadte the status
2. Need to write a polling service that checks if there are IP addresses or if IP address column in postgres is updated, then ping each of them and update the status, but how would service know a new IP was added or new set of IP addresses were added ?

Wondering if there is a better approach to handle the situation? I am confused on how I can design this feature.

Any suggestion or guidance is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The Publish / Subscribe model and a message broker such as RabbitMQ could help you achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Prometheus operator, running in Kubernetes, with Probe resource or Blackbox-exporter to do basic http probes.

So, rather than write to Postgres, use Kubernetes Go client to create such resources, which get stored in etcd database, instead.